# Debugging with Python Poetry and VS Code's SSH plugin

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote, python-poetry, vscode-python

The typical way to run VS Code with a Poetry environment is

```
$ poetry shell
(poetry environment) $ code .
```

However, this isn't possible when using VS Code's SSH plugin, which creates new remote shells as needed.

Only commands deemed necessary by VS Code and its plugins are run. Ideally the Python plugin would run `poetry shell`, but it doesn't at this time. Starting the Python debugger without the correct environment is not useful. I used VS Code's terminal window to type the command myself, but it had no effect. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You need to open VS Code and select the python interpreter that you wish to, typically the python executable that got created as a part of poetry's environment.